# Google Chrome - запрет загрузки определённого SWF

Tags: google-chrome, swf

В общем такой вопрос:
В Google Chrome нужно запретить загрузку определённого SWF, т.е. только единственного, только по 1 ссылке (назовём её http://site.ru/ads.swf) - как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Под Chrome же есть [Adblock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/en/chrome).

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно заблокировать всего лишь 1 ссылку - ставить из-за этого плагин не хочется. Возможно, можно где-то в настройках это сделать?

Comment: Плагин весит килобайт 300

Comment: Я не нашёл в моём Chrome возможность заблокировать адрес "из коробки". Кстати, Adblock Plus хорош, его стоит поставить даже просто для себя.